# How can I install React using NPM?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I can't install react using npm for some reason, I can't figure out what the problem is. Does anyone know a solution to this problem? I uninstalled npm and tried again but it didn't help and tried other things. but it doesn't help me.

```
stalling react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\darslar\imtihon-app\node_modules\tailwindcss\oxide-node-api-shim/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\darslar\imtihon-app\node_modules\tailwindcss\oxide-node-api-shim\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-08T15_57_28_764Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
node:fs:1226
  return handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
         ^

Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir '\\?\D:\darslar\imtihon-app'
    at rmdirSync (node:fs:1226:10)
    at _rmdirSync (node:internal/fs/rimraf:235:5)
    at rimrafSync (node:internal/fs/rimraf:193:7)
    at Object.rmSync (node:fs:1275:10)
    at Object.removeSync (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\remove\index.js:15:28)
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:539:14
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errno: -4082,
  syscall: 'rmdir',
  code: 'EBUSY',
}

Node.js v18.12.0
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post title should be a clear, specific question.

Comment: Turning _what_ off? Please revise to explain better what commands you ran.

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

- Delete `package-lock.json` and run NPM again.
- Ensure no other processes of node.js are running (check task manager)
- If you are using visual studio code, close it and try running npm install again.

You can also check the following issue page: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17444

Comment: i did everything you said and even restarted my computer to no avail :(

Comment: You can check the log that is in the 10th line in the error message. It also seems that npm cannot find the folder and the file. Make sure you are in the correct folder.

Comment: Everything is fine, I checked.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/10534#issuecomment-1422896616

Basically you need update npm to latest version

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Delete package-lock.json and node_modules and launch

```
npm i
```

It was a problem with dependency of cra. Whole world couldn`t install react for one hour.